# specialize only (a part of) one method of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

If I have a template class

```
template<typename T>
class C {
public:
    void method1() { ... }
    void method2() { ... }
    std::string method3(T &t) {
        // ...
        std::string s = t.SerializeToString();
        // ...
        return s;
    }
    // ...
};
```

and I want to specialize it for `T = std::string` but only changing `method3(T&)` (keeping all other methods), or even better, only that part of method3, which for `T = std::string` would simply become `std::string s = t;`, with minimum impact on current code (less repetition of methods signatures, less subclassing), how would I do it?

EDIT: I'm developing in C++11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use specialization like that (no need to specialize the whole class):

```
template<>
std::string C<string>::method3(string &t) {
    // ...
    std::string s = t;
    // ...
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I posted a minimal example, but in reality I do need to specialise the whole class

Comment: @fferri: you title literally says **"specialize only (a part of) one method of a template class"**.

Comment: @Jarod42: are you suggesting to remove the template parameter for the class? Or I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: @fferri it's called a template function.

Comment: @fferri: If you specialize the whole class, you have to rewrite `method1`/`method2` too. You can (fully) specialize only the given method. class is still template, method is not.

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to change `s`'s initialization, you can use overloading:

```
std::string init(std::string& t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
std::string init(T& t)
{
    return t.SerializeToString();
}

template <typename T>    
std::string method3(T &t) {
    // ...
    std::string s = init(t);
    // ...
    return s;
}
```

---

In C++17, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
std::string method3(T &t) 
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        std::string s = t;
        // ...
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string s = t.SerializeToString();
        // ...
        return s;
    }
}
```

---

In C++14, you can use [static_if](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k):

```
std::string method3(T &t) 
{
    static_if(std::is_same<T, std::string>{})
    .then([](auto& x)
    {
        std::string s = x;
        // ...
        return x;
    })
    .else_([](auto& x)
    {
        std::string s = x.SerializeToString();
        // ...
        return x;
    })(t);
}
```