# Template Specialisation with Template Argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, c++98

Let's suppose to have a `template`class `Foo`:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  void foo();
};
```

I have another `template` class `Bar` (independent from the first one):

```
template <int N>
class Bar {};
```

Let's say, I want to specialise the `foo()` method for whatever `Bar` class.
I'd wrongly write:

```
template <>
template <int N>
void Foo<Bar<N> >::foo() { /* ... */ }
```

The compiler blames me for because the type is not complete:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Foo<Bar<N> >'
 void Foo<Bar<N> >::foo() { }
```

[Code](https://godbolt.org/g/8ZDGzT)

I am using *C++98*, but I'd like to know if there exist different solutions in *C++11*.

---

#### Note

I could solve the problem specialising the entire class `Foo` for a generic `Bar`, but after I should have to define all methods.

[Example Code](https://godbolt.org/g/drrNk7)

That's not what I want, I am looking for (if exists) more elegant solution (both C++98 and C++11) which allows me to specialise and implement only a single class method.

---

#### EDIT:

[The question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035541/specialize-only-a-part-of-one-method-of-a-template-class) does not explain how to specialise with a template argument. Indeed, my question shows how the compiler complains about that.

Comment: Use a common base? Your example is too minimal, I think. It's not really so much trouble to fully specialize in this particular case.

Comment: What other types is `T` supposed to be? Do you need a value of `N` at specialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C++11 you can SFINAE enable/disable (using `std::enable_if`) two differents versions of `foo()` inside a not specialized `Foo` class.

<s>In C++98 you don't have `std::enable_if` but you can simulate it (give me some minutes and I try to propose an example).</s> Sorry: my idea doesn't works because this method require the use of default template arguments for methods that is a C++11 innovation.

Another way is define a template base class for `Foo()`, say `FooBase`, insert `foo()` (and only `foo()`) in `FooBase` and specialize `FooBase`.

Another way, that works also with C++98, can be tag dispatching: you can define an unique `foo()`, with zero parameter, that call another `foo()`, with a parameter that is determined by `T`.

The following is a full (C++98 compilable) example

```
#include <iostream>

struct barWay   {};
struct noBarWay {};

template <int>
struct Bar
 { };

template <typename>
struct selectType
 { typedef noBarWay type; };

template <int N>
struct selectType< Bar<N> >
 { typedef barWay type; };

template <typename T>
struct Foo
 {
   void foo (noBarWay const &)
    { std::cout << "not Bar version" << std::endl; }

   void foo (barWay const &)
    { std::cout << "Bar version" << std::endl; }

   void foo ()
    { foo(typename selectType<T>::type()); }
 };


int main ()
 {
   Foo<int>        fi;
   Foo< Bar<42> >  fb;

   fi.foo();
   fb.foo(); 
 }
```

Comment: Could always point them to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if so they have visibility of usage and potential implementation.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - believe or not, I didn't think to see cppreference and I've implemented it ex novo (forgetting the `void` default value :( ). Anyway, my idea doesn't work because need a C++11 feature.

Answer (score 0):

if a common base is not desirable, yet another way could be giving foo() a customization point, like a trait for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_traits;

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  void foo(){ foo_traits<T>::foo_cp(*this); }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo_traits{ static void foo_cp(T&){/*default*/} };

template <int N>
class Bar {};

template <int N>
struct foo_traits<Bar<N>>{ static void foo_cp(Foo<Bar<N>>&){/*spec*/} };
```

such trait could also be an implementation detail friend, if its only purpose is to internally provide a foo() specialization for Bar's.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot specialize `foo`, define it so that it delegates the call to an internal *foo-implementation* class. Then specialize that class.
Something like this should compile in C++98 and it doesn't differ much from your original code:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    template<typename>
    struct FooImpl;

public:
    void foo() { FooImpl<T>()(); }
};

template <int N>
class Bar {};

template <typename T>
template <int N>
struct Foo<T>::FooImpl< Bar<N> > {
    void operator()() { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {
    Foo< Bar<0> > fb;
    fb.foo();

    Foo<int> fi;
    //fi.foo();
}
```

The last line doesn't compile as expected (at least I got it was the expected result, just define the function call operator for `FooImpl` otherwise).

This way you can define selectively the specializations for which you want `foo` to work. In all the other cases, an attempt at using `foo` will result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know if there exist different solutions in *C++11*.

This is a classic use case for tagged dispatch, of which [max66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162280/27678) already suggested. The approach, and even syntax, are basically the same in C++98 and C++11.

Here's a bit of a cleaner implementation than max66's, I believe ([running on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/DCVVvo)):

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
    template <class>
    struct tag{};
    template<class U>
    void foo_helper(tag<U>){std::cout << "default\n";}
    void foo_helper(tag<Bar<3> >){std::cout << "specialization for Bar<3>\n";}
public:
    void foo(){return foo_helper(tag<T>());}
};
```

The principle is the same; a client function accepting no arguments calls a helper function that constructs an empty type based on the `T` argument. Then normal overloading takes care of the rest.

Only here I use a templated catch-all method.

---

In C++11 the syntax would only change slightly; We could say `tag<Bar<3>>` instead of `tag<Bar<3> >` because new parsing rules allow the chevron for nested templates.

We could also make the tag and the templated `foo_helper` catch-all into [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to be a little more generic:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
    template <class...>
    struct tag{};
    template<class... U>
    void foo_helper(tag<U...>){std::cout << "default\n";}
    void foo_helper(tag<Bar<3>>){std::cout << "specialization for Bar<3>\n";}
public:
    void foo(){return foo_helper(tag<T>{});}
};
```

---

Things actually start getting pretty interesting in **C++17** with the introduction of [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) that allows us to write what looks like normal branching logic based on `T` ([Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/61Obk1qFJEbERU6c)):

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
    void foo(){
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Bar<3>>){std::cout << "Specialization for Bar<3>\n";}
        else std::cout << "default\n";
    }
};
```

As you can see, all the tag stuff goes away in favor of using a simple if statement.

We take advantage of [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) introduced in C++11 to check the type of `T` against our desired type. Something like this wouldn't necessarily work previously because all branches needed to be compiled. In C++17, only the branch that is selected (at compile-time) is compiled.

Note that you could emulate this behavior as early as C++98 by using [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) ([godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/g/51xQX4)):

```
void foo(){
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(Bar<3>)){std::cout << "Specialization for Bar<3>\n";}
    else std::cout << "default\n";
}
```

However, the `typeid` approach is a poor choice for 2 reasons:

1. It's a run time check (slow) for information we know at compile-time
2. It's brittle because all branches must compile for all template instantiations, whereas in C++17 `if constexpr` only compiles the branch that is selected.